# MongoDB Atlas Online Archive - Unable to Connect from EC2 with VPC Peering (MongoNetworkError)

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, mongodb-atlas, mongo-archive

We have configured mongo atlas archiving and trying to connect with aws ec2 with the help of VPC peering. We have already established vpc peering to connect Primary database and it is working fine. But in case of archive db connection we are having connection issue, if we try with ip whitelist then it works fine.

Can any one help us to connect mongo archive db with vpc peering.

Error while connecting with mongo shell

> 2020-12-12T05:41:15.283+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to `xx.xxx.xx.xx:port` after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up.
> 2020-12-12T05:41:15.283+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server atlas-online-archive-5da8542bcf09a2545f54fa24-jsraa.a.query.mongodb.net:27017, connection attempt failed :
> connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:275:13
> @(connect):1:6
> exception: connect failed

Answer (score 0):

> Atlas provides a unified endpoint through which you can query both your live cluster and archived data using the same database and collection name you use in your Atlas cluster. You can't use the unified endpoint over a private connection such as Peering or AWS PrivateLink. You must use a standard internet connection over TLS.

https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/online-archive/manage-online-archive/#how-service-archives-data

Unfortunately VPC peering is not supported when connecting to the Online Archive

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue.

VPC Peering works fine with normal cluster endpoint, but doesn't connect to MongoDB Atlas's [Online Archive](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/online-archive/manage-online-archive/) Cluster Endpoint.

You can now set up a [Private Endpoint for Online Archive](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/online-archive/config-private-endpoint/).

Summarized steps:

1. Navigate to the Network Access page for your project
2. Click the Private Endpoint tab and then the following tab
3. Click Federated Database Instance / Online Archive for a private endpoint for your federated database instance or online archive
4. Click Create New Endpoint button.
5. Choose an AWS region
6. Configure your private endpoint

   - Your VPC ID
   - Your Subnet IDs
   - Copy the command the dialog displays and run it using the AWS CLI. ([See Creating an Interface Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/create-interface-endpoint.html#create-interface-endpoint))
7. Enter your VPC Endpoint ID. This is a 22-character alphanumeric string that identifies your private endpoint. Find this value on the AWS VPC Dashboard under Endpoints > VPC ID.
8. Enter the alpha-numeric DNS hostname associated with your private endpoint on AWS in the Your VPC Endpoint DNS Name field. If you have multiple DNS names for your private endpoint, copy and paste the first name from your list.

Extra Steps NOT in docs:

- For the VPC Endpoint, create/attach new security group with sufficient inbound rules (I set mines to 0.0.0.0/0 since my VPC is private)

Thumbs up if this helped!